# unexpected $nd expecting keyword end

Tags: ruby

```
class CSUN
def initialize()
# create hashes 
@lastnamehash = Hash.new( )
@firstname = Hash.new( )
@major = Hash.new( )
@catalogyear = Hash.new( )
puts "database created"
end


# Add Record
def addrecord ()
#Prompt for LastName, FrstName, Major, Catalog Year
print "Enter Student's Last name: "
lastname = gets.chomp

print "Enter Student's First Name: "
firstname = gets.chomp

Print "Enter Student's ID: "
id = gets.chomp

Print "Enter Student's Major: "
major = gets.chomp

Print "Enter Catalog Year: "
catalogyear = gets.chomp


if (@lastnamehash [ID])
    puts "Student Already Exists!"
    return
end 

#store in hash
@lastnamehash[ID] = lastname
@firstnamehash[ID] = firstname
@majorhash[ID] = major
@catalogyearhash[ID] = catalogyear
end


#update record
def updaterecord()
#Prompt for record by ID
print "Enter Student's ID: "
    id=gets.chomp
    if !(@lastnameash [ID])
    puts "Record does not exist"
    return
else
    puts "Update Student's Last Name"
    puts "current value: #{@lastnamehash [ID]}"
    print "New Value: "
    lastname = gets.chomp
    @lastnamehash[ID] = lastname


    puts "Update Student's First Name"
    puts "current value: #{@firstnamehash [ID]}"
    print "New Value: "
    firstname = gets.chomp
    @firstnamehash[ID] = firstname

    puts "Update Student's major"
    puts "current value: #{@majorhash [ID]}"
    print "New Value: "
    major = gets.chomp
    @majorhash[ID] = major

    puts "Update Student's catalog year"
    puts "current value: #{@catalogyearhash [ID]}"
    print "New Value: "
    catalogyear = gets.chomp
    @catalogyearhash[ID] = catalogyear


end
end

#delete record
def deleterecord()

if !(@lastnameash [ID])
    puts "Record does not exist"
    return
    else
    @lastnamehash.delete(ID)
    @firstnamehash.delete(ID)
    @majorhash.delete(ID)
    @catalogyear.delete(ID)
    puts"Record Deleted"
end
    #printrecord( )
    def printrecord( )
    @lastnamehash.each do |key,value|
    puts "Student ID: #{key}"
    puts "Last name: #{value}"
    puts "First name: #{@firstnamehash[key]}"
    puts "Major: #{@majorhash[key]}"
    puts "Catalog Year: #{@catalogyearhash[key]}"
end


#save record
def saverecord()
print "save record (y/n): "
save1 = gets.chomp
if save1!= "y"
    return
else
savefile = File.new("records.dat","w")
contents = " "
    @lastnamehash.each do |key,value|
    contents = contents + key + values + @firstnamehash[key] + majorhash[key] + catalogyearhash
end

savefiles.syswrite (contents)
savefiles.close()
puts"contents saved"
end

#main loop
choice = 0
while (choice !=6)
#propmt for choice
choice = gets.chomp
case(choice)
    when"1";
        db = CSUN.new
    when"2"
        db.addrecord
    when"3"
        db.updaterecord
    when"4"
        db.deleterecord
    when"5"
        db.printrecord
    when"6"
        db.saverecord
end
end
end
```

I keep getting this error "unexpected $nd expecting keyword end"
So I know why I am getting this error I just cant figure out which end is causing it

I need fresh eyes to point me in the right direction!

Comment: What you need first is proper indentation.

Comment: Bad indentation is BAD m'kay? Most missing-end problems come about because you personally can't keep track of begins and ends... if you indent - it always becomes much clearer (just run your eyes down the code until you find an indentation that doesn't have an end and you've got it)

Comment: My answer shows proper indentation of your code, thus easy to spot the missing elements. If you're using something like vim or a good editor, it will usually have a cleanup/fix indentation feature. In vim you can highlight your code (shift + v and then navigate to end of code) and press equals. There are plenty of shortcuts to do it

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `end` before `def printrecord( )`, an `end` before `saverecord()` and then a final `end` on the very last line. Please indent your code!

Answer (score 1):

Proper indentation goes along way for large Classes and nested conditional statements.  I believe your problem at the `deleterecord` method.  You closed out the conditional statement
but need another `end` to close out the method.  The same goes for the `printmethod!`

```
def deleterecord  
  if
    code
  else
    code
  end
NEED ANOTHER end HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrect in your assessment that one of the `end`s is causing the problem.  On the contrary, you need several more `end`s to make everything balance.  Indenting your code (or using a text editor made for writing code) will make this obvious.

Adding an `end` before `printrecord`, another before `seaverecord`, and two more before the main loop seems to be what you meant and results in a working program.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs quite a bit of help with indentation and spacing. If you fix that it's easier to find missing elements

```
class CSUN
  def initialize()
    # create hashes 
    @lastnamehash = Hash.new( )
    @firstname = Hash.new( )
    @major = Hash.new( )
    @catalogyear = Hash.new( )
    puts "database created"
  end

  # Add Record
  def addrecord ()
    #Prompt for LastName, FrstName, Major, Catalog Year
    print "Enter Student's Last name: "
    lastname = gets.chomp

    print "Enter Student's First Name: "
    firstname = gets.chomp

    Print "Enter Student's ID: "
    id = gets.chomp

    Print "Enter Student's Major: "
    major = gets.chomp

    Print "Enter Catalog Year: "
    catalogyear = gets.chomp

    if (@lastnamehash [ID])
      puts "Student Already Exists!"
      return
    end 

    #store in hash
    @lastnamehash[ID] = lastname
    @firstnamehash[ID] = firstname
    @majorhash[ID] = major
    @catalogyearhash[ID] = catalogyear
  end

  #update record
  def updaterecord()
    #Prompt for record by ID
    print "Enter Student's ID: "
    id=gets.chomp
    if !(@lastnameash [ID])
      puts "Record does not exist"
      return
    else
      puts "Update Student's Last Name"
      puts "current value: #{@lastnamehash [ID]}"
      print "New Value: "
      lastname = gets.chomp
      @lastnamehash[ID] = lastname

      puts "Update Student's First Name"
      puts "current value: #{@firstnamehash [ID]}"
      print "New Value: "
      firstname = gets.chomp
      @firstnamehash[ID] = firstname

      puts "Update Student's major"
      puts "current value: #{@majorhash [ID]}"
      print "New Value: "
      major = gets.chomp
      @majorhash[ID] = major

      puts "Update Student's catalog year"
      puts "current value: #{@catalogyearhash [ID]}"
      print "New Value: "
      catalogyear = gets.chomp
      @catalogyearhash[ID] = catalogyear
    end
  end

  #delete record
  def deleterecord()
    if !(@lastnameash [ID])
      puts "Record does not exist"
      return
    else
      @lastnamehash.delete(ID)
      @firstnamehash.delete(ID)
      @majorhash.delete(ID)
      @catalogyear.delete(ID)
      puts"Record Deleted"
    end
```

MISSING END

```
  #printrecord( )
  def printrecord( )
    @lastnamehash.each do |key,value|
    puts "Student ID: #{key}"
    puts "Last name: #{value}"
    puts "First name: #{@firstnamehash[key]}"
    puts "Major: #{@majorhash[key]}"
    puts "Catalog Year: #{@catalogyearhash[key]}"
  end

  #save record
  def saverecord()
    print "save record (y/n): "
    save1 = gets.chomp
    if save1!= "y"
      return
    else
      savefile = File.new("records.dat","w")
      contents = " "
      @lastnamehash.each do |key,value|
        contents = contents + key + values + @firstnamehash[key] + majorhash[key] + catalogyearhash
      end

      savefiles.syswrite (contents)
      savefiles.close()
      puts"contents saved"
    end

    #main loop
    choice = 0

    while (choice !=6)
      #propmt for choice
      choice = gets.chomp
      case(choice)
      when"1";
        db = CSUN.new
      when"2"
        db.addrecord
      when"3"
        db.updaterecord
      when"4"
        db.deleterecord
      when"5"
        db.printrecord
      when"6"
        db.saverecord
      end
    end
  end
```

MISSING END

Answer (score 0):

You miss three times end . your 100% working code is

```
class CSUN
  def initialize()
    # create hashes 
    @lastnamehash = Hash.new( )
    @firstname = Hash.new( )
    @major = Hash.new( )
    @catalogyear = Hash.new( )
    puts "database created"
  end


  # Add Record
  def addrecord ()
    #Prompt for LastName, FrstName, Major, Catalog Year
    print "Enter Student's Last name: "
    lastname = gets.chomp

    print "Enter Student's First Name: "
    firstname = gets.chomp

    Print "Enter Student's ID: "
    id = gets.chomp

    Print "Enter Student's Major: "
    major = gets.chomp

    Print "Enter Catalog Year: "
    catalogyear = gets.chomp


    if (@lastnamehash [ID])
        puts "Student Already Exists!"
        return
    end 

    #store in hash
    @lastnamehash[ID] = lastname
    @firstnamehash[ID] = firstname
    @majorhash[ID] = major
    @catalogyearhash[ID] = catalogyear
  end


  #update record
  def updaterecord()
    #Prompt for record by ID
    print "Enter Student's ID: "
    id=gets.chomp
    if !(@lastnameash [ID])
        puts "Record does not exist"
        return
    else
        puts "Update Student's Last Name"
        puts "current value: #{@lastnamehash [ID]}"
        print "New Value: "
        lastname = gets.chomp
        @lastnamehash[ID] = lastname


        puts "Update Student's First Name"
        puts "current value: #{@firstnamehash [ID]}"
        print "New Value: "
        firstname = gets.chomp
        @firstnamehash[ID] = firstname

        puts "Update Student's major"
        puts "current value: #{@majorhash [ID]}"
        print "New Value: "
        major = gets.chomp
        @majorhash[ID] = major

        puts "Update Student's catalog year"
        puts "current value: #{@catalogyearhash [ID]}"
        print "New Value: "
        catalogyear = gets.chomp
        @catalogyearhash[ID] = catalogyear


    end
  end

  #delete record
  def deleterecord()

    if !(@lastnameash [ID])
        puts "Record does not exist"
        return
    else
        @lastnamehash.delete(ID)
        @firstnamehash.delete(ID)
        @majorhash.delete(ID)
        @catalogyear.delete(ID)
        puts"Record Deleted"
    end
  end
  #printrecord( )
  def printrecord( )
    @lastnamehash.each do |key,value|
      puts "Student ID: #{key}"
      puts "Last name: #{value}"
      puts "First name: #{@firstnamehash[key]}"
      puts "Major: #{@majorhash[key]}"
      puts "Catalog Year: #{@catalogyearhash[key]}"
    end

  end
  #save record
  def saverecord()
    print "save record (y/n): "
    save1 = gets.chomp
    if save1!= "y"
      return
    else
      savefile = File.new("records.dat","w")
      contents = " "
      @lastnamehash.each do |key,value|
        contents = contents + key + values + @firstnamehash[key] + majorhash[key] + catalogyearhash
      end

      savefiles.syswrite(contents)
      savefiles.close()
      puts"contents saved"
    end

    #main loop
    choice = 0
    while (choice !=6)
      #propmt for choice
      choice = gets.chomp
      case(choice)
      when"1";
        db = CSUN.new
      when"2"
        db.addrecord
      when"3"
        db.updaterecord
      when"4"
        db.deleterecord
      when"5"
        db.printrecord
      when"6"
        db.saverecord
      end
    end
  end
end
```

for future reference always use netbeans 6.9.1 this type of error